# CSS selector not working, why?

Tags: css, css-selectors, substring

I have this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5zvV/).

I am trying to obtain the value of the `repositoryId` on Line 238:

```
<a href="/chain/admin/config/editRepository.action?planKey=AB-CSD&amp;repositoryId=28049450">
```

In the case above it would be `28049450`. I tried:

```
#panel-editor-list > ul
```

But this is not working, any ideas on what it should be? Also, to help me in the future, **why** isn't this working?

Comment: are you trying to get a substring of `href` using css and css selectors??

Comment: Thanks @BeNdErR (+1) - ultimately yes, I'm looking for the "repositoryId" substring, but would settle for the `href` (I can always parse the substring out afterwards).

Comment: you need to use js to parse the href value..

Comment: @IAmYourFaja A CSS selector can match the Element by the presence of the substring -- e.g. [`a[href*="repositoryId=28049450"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). But, it isn't capable of retrieving the substring itself.

Comment: Looking at your other questions, you appear to be using jsoup rather than CSS. If that's the case, it might not be wise to tag your question with just [css] as the language because that implies you're trying to style something with CSS - and you can't do anything meaningful with just an attribute value in CSS. (The [css-selectors] tag should be fine since jsoup also uses CSS selectors to select elements.)

Answer (score 1):

you can't get the value of a querystring pair with css

Comment: Thanks @Mindexperiment, but what about `li.item.item-default > a`, wouldn't that work?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja That could be used to select the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) itself. But, CSS cannot alone proceed beyond that to parse and extract a particular query-string value from the Element's attribute. It is not a complete programming language with string processing and data structures.